# I want to separate my digits with a comma from right to left (digit grouping)

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I use this code to separate my number with comma:
`jQuery(this).val((jQuery(this).val().replace(/(\d{3}(?!,))/g, "$1,")));`

- if my number is `12345` it will become `123,45`
- but I want the separating comma from the right, i.e. `12,345`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your `number` is a `string` or `number` itself with **no** comma at all **then** You can simply use [toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) method to display `commas` between `thousands`

**Demo:**

```js
let str1  = parseInt('1234').toLocaleString('en')
let str2  = parseInt('12345').toLocaleString('en')
let str3  = parseInt('123456').toLocaleString('en')

console.log(str1)
console.log(str2)
console.log(str3)
```

Comment: This is the best internationalized way, as `,` is not everywhere the grouping separator and 3 digits is not everywhere the grouping amount. In DE/AT/FR a proper grouping would be `1.024.000`, in CH a proper grouping would be `2'048'000`, in IN it would be `40,96,000`...

Answer (score 2):

Did you try the following?

```js
function numberWithCommas(x) {
    return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}

console.log(numberWithCommas(12345)); // Output: "12,345"
console.log(numberWithCommas(123456789)); // Output: "123,456,789"
```

Have a look here for more details -  [How to print a number with commas as thousands separators in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

A way to go is to replace

- `(?<=\d)(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))`

with

- `,`

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/WhoTLY/1)